# Azure Service fabric ,access Application via domain name

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-ad-graph-api

My  Requirement  is  to  Access  Fabric Application  based  on  Tenant Domain

```
eg:  i  had  3  services  

1)CustomerApps
2)CompanyApps
3)SignInApps

All  the   above  apps  deployed  on  azure   service  fabric  Cluster
```

i  already   created  Custom  Domain  in  Azure  Active  directory  and Verify  that  Domain  with  Register(eg:  godady)

```
So,  now   i  want  to  display   each  fabric  Application  based  on  Tenant/Domain  name like, assumed  i  had  custom  domain  dev-tennat.xyz.com

so,application   url  will  be  
dev-tennat.xyz.com/SignInApps
dev-tennat.xyz.com/CompanyApps
dev-tennat.xyz.com/CustomerApps
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your domain for example “your-domain.xyz.com” should be A type and has to point to your load balancer public IP. You can find IP under overview of your load balancer.

lbip

2) You need to configure custom probe for your load balances.

```
go to “Probes” under “Settings” category.
Select HTTP protocol
i’ve set port to 80 as i wanted something to be visible by default
In “Path” field you specify endpoint you want to expose it can be “/” or “/api/customapi”
Interval – set value in seconds. Every ‘n’ seconds your “Path” will be triggered to check if app is alive
```

3) You need to configure custom rule

Go to “Load balancing rules” under “Settings” category and create new rule. When creating new rule:

```
“Port” is your publicly exposed port (80 in my case),
“Backend port” is internal port of your app (you can find it in service manifest in <EndPoint /> element. In my case it’s 8164)
```

In “Probe” field select your probe which was created before.

There are some screenshots if needed:
https://eduardlos.wordpress.com/2016/10/10/how-to-access-your-app-when-deployed-to-azure-service-fabric-cluster/